# Showing select option label from ACF using timber

Tags: select, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I would like to be able to show the select label rather than the value when returning data from a select field in timber using ACF

I can get the list of fields by using the code below but this is all fields not the one related to the record.

`{{senior.field_object('job_sector').choices|print_r}}`

Answer (score 1):

How did you set up your ACF field? For the [Select Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/select/) you can either use the value, the label or both the value and the label as a **Return Value**. So I’m assuming if you returned both, that would be the easiest way to solve this.

But the following might also work, assuming that `senior` is a post object and `job_sector` is the name of the select field.

```
{{ senior.field_object('job_sector').choices[senior.meta('job_sector')] }}
```

By using `senior.meta('job_sector')`, you select the value, which is the key to get the label in the `choices` array.